# Rails custom model validator depending on check_box value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, checkbox, model

Lets say i have a model "Blog" with :title and :body.
Lets also say that in my view I have input for title, body and a check_box_tag that looks like this

```
<%= check_box_tag "published" %>
```

Now, I want to write a custom validation for the :body that should run only if my checkbox "published" is checked.

The question is - **how do i get the value of the ckeckbox since :published is not a model attribute**?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Neither should you.

Validations ensure the buisness logic in the context of a instance of a model. Not a request. If you want to provide any other context to a validation you have to pass it into the model - and that data has to be saved somewhere until the validation callback is performed - in an attribute. This does not necissarily mean that it has to be a database column.

If you do want to get an parameter in the controller they can be found in the parameters hash according to the name attribute of the input.

```
params[:published]
```

Comment: All right, thank You. I got the value of the checkbox in my controller but how do i add the validation error depending on its value?

Comment: `object.errors.add(:keyname)`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add